# Block misbehaving user facebook sdk ios

Tags: ios, facebook-sdk-4.x

im building a simple app where users can collaborate with each other but there is a small chance that some of them will decide to post fake information for everyone else to see. This would really affect the app's efficacy so I was wondering if anybody knows a good way of "blocking" access to a specific user to the app using the Facebook sdk in ios9. Currently, if you don't login you cannot use the app at all but I am wondering if there is a way to block a specific person and prevent them from using the app altogether or at least decrease their privileges when using it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To ban a user from using your app you can `POST` to the `/v2.6/{app-id}/banned` edge, with the name and value: `uid={user-id}`

An example using iOS SDK:

```
NSDictionary *params = @{
  @"uid": @"1234",
};

FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]
                               initWithGraphPath:@"/{app-id}/banned"
                                      parameters:params
                                      HTTPMethod:@"POST"];

[request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection,
                                      id result,
                                      NSError *error) {
    // Handle the result
}];
```

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.6/app/banned